# How to pass NFC tag to other Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, tags, nfc

In my code there are three Activities, each of them need to work with NFC tag, so I need to have this tag on all of them, but I have just one tag in one Activity. so I need to send it to the other activities
the only way which worked for me is to add tag as extra in Intent and start Intent Activity.

This way is not effective, because every time I need to go to this activity, I need to send a tag without going to another activity.

do any one have idea how to send Tag to another activity?

Comment: Declare your TAG in the first activity which could use it, as global: static Tag TAG = null. In the other activities you can access it with activityName.TAG.

Comment: I've tried this way it returns me a null tag . what I found until now is to send the the tag in intent by putExtra , or to pass the tag as parameter to another class using constractor.